# msgpack to pack structures

Tags: c++, sockets, data-structures, msgpack

I have the following structure (among many others) and I want to send it over a socket.

```
struct Position
{
    float x; // position selon x
    float y; // position selon y
    float theta; // orientation % z
    Position (float x_, float y_, float theta_): x(x_), y(y_), theta(theta_){}
    Position(){}
};
```

But first, for decoding purposes, I thought about using [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) library for coding and decoding as it may simplify my task greatly.

Only problem is that I couldn't figure out how exactly can I do that, almost all the examples available here and elsewhere are trying just to pack conventional buffers (vectors, lists...) but no structure packing I can found !

So, Can it be done and how is that do-able ?

PS : the structure example is simplified, I got some that are seriously more complicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's doable. You can use `MSGPACK_DEFINE_MAP` or `MSGPACK_DEFINE_ARRAY`:

```
struct Position
{
    float x; // position selon x
    float y; // position selon y
    float theta; // orientation % z
    Position (float x_, float y_, float theta_): x(x_), y(y_), theta(theta_){}
    Position(){}
    MSGPACK_DEFINE_MAP(x, y, theta)
};
```

This macro will generate the required adapter functions.

The difference is that the array will just list your members (thus being more compact), while the map will contain the struct members as key-value pairs.

Source: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v1_1_cpp_adaptor#defining-custom-adaptors

Comment: But what if its not my own struct? The example [here](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_adaptor) only shows how to pack arrays.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig the purpose of these macros is to add metadata to gain the names and addresses of the members required for serialization. This is a feature that C++ lacks so you always have to do extra work. On the page you linked it shows a similar example for structs as mine. You can also try the [non-intrusive](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_adaptor#non-intrusive-approach) approach where you can serialize someone else's class - but it's going to be a lot of work. You might be able to metaprogram around it a bit with Boost.Hana, but again, lots of work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have seen the docs for the non-intrusive approach, but sadly they lack the required details on how to actually do an implementation. I don’t doing lots of work for this, but without proper documentation or an example I am lost.